# Laravel: Llamar a una función del controlador desde el blade, pasándole un parámetro

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

Buenos días,

estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Laravel y Vue.js y tengo una duda.
Estoy mostrando en una tabla información de la base de datos, pero en ella aparece el "id" de un registro y quiero que aparezca el nombre. Por tanto quiero llamar a una función del controlador para que devuelva el nombre según el id.

Mi código en la vista es el siguiente:

```
    <tr v-for="item in items">
        <td>@{{ item.nombre }}</td>
        <td>@{{ item.descripcion }}</td>
        <td>@{{ item.coordenadaX }}</td>
        <td>@{{ item.coordenadaY }}</td>
        <td>@{{ item.zona_idZona }}></td> //Este es el parámetro que quiero 
                                            enviar a la función del 
                                             controlador
```

Mi función en el controlador

```
  public function sacar_nombre($identificador){
     $nombre = UsuarioM::where('id', '=', $identificador)->select('nombre');
           return $nombre;
  }
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No debes enviar el valor desde la vista al controlador. Primero debes obtener todos los valores en el controlador, cuando ya tienes todo lo que necesitas, llamas a la vista para mostrar la información.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero tengo otra duda. Tengo la tabla "Toma" y la tabla "Zona", por lo tanto tengo un modelo para cada una donde mapeo la tabla de la base de datos. Mi pregunta es cómo consigo juntar las dos para poder conseguir el nombre?. No se si debo modificar los modelos o los controladores. En el controlador de "Toma", realizo una consulta para obtener los datos de la siguiente manera 
$items = TomaM::latest()->paginate(5);                                             Puede ser que haciendo una consulta con un join obtenga el nombre y lo pueda mostrar?

Comment: Se puede realizar como dices, en el controlador puedes realizar el `join` de ambas tablas y así obtener el nombre, pero no es la manera correcta. Lo mejor es cofigurar el modelo para que tenga la relación al otro modelo. De esta manera puedes acceder fácilmente desde el primer modelo la información del otro modelo. Puedes leer sobre esto en la documentación oficial: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one